# Assigning multiple values in a combo box to multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to create a search box using a combo box in Excel where it retrieves data from a two column table in excel. I have a simple excel spreadsheet table with two columns as follows,

```
ID   | Name 
001  | Peter
002  |  James
```

So far, the combo box I have created retrieves the row data (ID & Name) successfully when I type a keyword. But when I select one it only outputs the data values to one cell A5. (Assume linked cell is A5)

For ex: 
If I select "001  Peter" from combo box it outputs only "001" to the linked cell value in combo box. How can I assign two column values (ID & Name) to two different cells when selected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the text in the ComboBox has every thing you want to send to cell A5 then the code would be

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Range("A5").Value = ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

This is providing your ComboBox is ComboBox1 - look out for this if you have other ComboBoxes on the sheet

Comment: It outputs only the value "001" to the cell A5. I want the values "001" to be inserted to A5 and "Peter" to be inserted to B5 when selected.

Comment: What method are you using to get info from two separate columns in to a single combobox?